# GAMSession object GetApplicationData

Tags: c#, genexus

```
GX17u6 
C#
```

Estoy usando ExternalLogin entre mi sistema y otro de un tercero también desarrollado en GX en version evo3. En el sistema externo, existe un servicio que realiza el login (**agamwslogin_v20Local**) y carga un sdt con datos adicionales.

Luego, en mi sistema intento recuperar los datos del sdt usando `GAMSession.GetApplicationData()` como dice en esta [doc](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21575,GetApplicationData%20method%20of%20GAMSession%20object) y resulta que no compila:

```
&MEMO=GAMSession.GetApplicationData()
GuardoLogTXT.Call(&Pgmname+"#&MEMO: "+&MEMO.Trim())

&GAMSession = GAMSession.Get(&Errors)
GuardoLogTXT.Call(&Pgmname+"#&GAMSession:"+&GAMSession.ToJsonString().Trim())
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
error spc0017: Expression "GeneXusSecurity\GAMSession.getapplicationdata()" does not return a value.
```

Lo raro es que desde GX brinda la posibilidad de ejecutar ese método desde **GAMSession**.

Intenté luego obtener los datos del sdt cargado obteniendo la &GAMSession y no es posible, posee solo información del usuario y la sesion pero no los datos cargados manualmente en origen.
Como dato adicional puedo decir que tengo una situación idéntica funcionando correctamente con GX16u3 sin problemas.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Bruno, como estas? Seguramente el problema que estas teniendo es que estas guardando los datos en una variable con el tipo incorrecto. Te podes fijar que el tipo de &MEMO sea igual a "GAMSessionSharedData" ? Gracias

Comment: El tipo de &MEMO es LongVarChar y se supone que  GAMSession.GetApplicationData() también. Lo mas insólito es que dejando la linea de codigo GAMSession.GetApplicationData() sin una variable que reciba compilaba (pero obviamente no hace lo que espero).

Comment: Ok, entiendo, yo hice una prueba con el domain y me funciona ok en evo3, probaria por las dudas asignandole el domain aunque sea del mismo type.